# Governing Limits for the Square-Connect API

Tags: square-connect

Does anybody know if there are any governing limits on the usage of the API.

1. How many times can we query data (payments, refunds etc)

2. Is there an upper limit on the volume of data that can be queries at once or during an hour or a day?

3. Please explain as to why the data access is slow. I tried to use batch retrieval and it takes me 15 seconds on average to fetch 16 payments.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your questions. Answers below.

1 & 2: The Square Connect API does implement rate limiting, but these limits are not currently disclosed. Newly added to the [documentation](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api#ratelimiting):

> If Connect API endpoints receive too many requests associated with the same application or access token in a short time window, they might respond with a **429 Too Many Requests** error. If this occurs, try your request again at a later time.

In practice, the limit is currently on the order of 10 QPS.

3: Thanks for pointing out this issue with the batch endpoint. This is a known bug that we are actively working to resolve. We'll update this answer when a fix is live.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! I do have a few clarifications:
1. Not to be too picky, but what is too many requests? Also what is the unit of time that you are using to measure the number of requests.
2. Thanks, I look forward to receiving an update on this point.

Thanks again

Comment: I've updated the answer to indicate the current rate limit (on the order of 10 QPS)